# Mule 3.7CE enabling jmx

Tags: mule, jmx

i'm trying to get JMX monitoring to work on a Mule 3.7 CE server.
I've got a flow with

```
 <management:jmx-server >
  <management:connector-server url="service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://my-server:1099/server" rebind="false" />
  </management:jmx-server>
```

when i deploy the app it get this error

> - Failed to deploy artifact 'jmx_ce37', see below          +
>     ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException:
>     RegistrationException: More than one object of type class
>     org.mule.module.management.agent.AbstractJmxAgent registered but only
>     one expected.     at
>     org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:197)
>     ~[?:?]

I would assume that there's already some jmx process running; but i didn't enable it, and i don't know how to connect to it. There are no processes listening on the default jmx port (1096) on this machine.
Any suggestions on what to do to use jmx with Mule3.7CE ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mule server already provides indeed a JMX server with basic statistics around the server and the applications, please try and use a different port if the default out-of-the-box behaviuor does not work for you.

Comment: any idea on how to get the port-nr that the Mule jmx instance is using? Is there some config file where i can look? (the wrapper.conf doesn't seem to contain anything jmx related) It's not the default 1096. Doesn't matter which port i use in my mule-app, i always get the same error. It looks like the only option i've got is to connect to the mule-jmx instance.

Comment: By default you can connect to the process running jconsole or visual vm in the same host, you would need to add the explicit system properties in wrapper.conf if you want to open it for remote access i.e: wrapper.java.additional.5=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
wrapper.java.additional.6=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999
wrapper.java.additional.7=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
wrapper.java.additional.8=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false